# Burnination of device tag

Tags: discussion, tags

The tag [devices](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/devices) serves no purpose.  Can we please burninate?

Comment: Yes, please! :D

Comment: `[peripherals]` might be another one. Or `[accessories]`

Comment: [[tag:devices]] covers internal hardware also... [[tag:peripherals]] and or [[tag:accessories]] does not!

Answer (score 1):

I object. 
There must be separate tags: one for internal hardware and another one for pluggable hardware: printers, home routers, whatever. Someone would want to subscribe to one, not another. To have a separate tag for any device would make too many of them. 
[Peripherals] may be good replacement, but just dropping the [device] tag would loose the information and automatic renaming would bring confusion. Just leave it be.

Comment: We already have individual tags for `printer`, `scanner`, `mouse`, `keyboard`, `trackpad`, `usb-hub`, `docking-station`, `external-hard-drive`, `usb-flash-drive`, `mobile-phone`, `modem`, `dongle`, `monitor`, `nas`, `router`, `wireless-router`, `wireless-access-point`... and probably a lot more I didn't find just now. How is `devices` more useful, or as useful, as the more specific alternatives? How do you suggest the tag be used? Is it actually used that way?

Comment: In pair with individual tag. If I am skilled in that sort of devices, I would like to browse questions on them all, not one by one. On StackOverflow we have tags like [Java] [Python], not only [function] [class] [inheritance]. As long as no hierarhy of tags supported, we should have global and more specific tags side-by-side. By saying this I presume tags are intended to find questions one can answer, not just to omit stating your OS in question text.

Comment: Isn't `device` is the equivalent to `programming-language` (as opposed to e.g. `framework`?). `python` is more like `printer`...

Comment: `device` is so broad it is useless. A programming-language tag is more akin to naming your operating system or architecture, which is actually useful and will be relevant to answering the question.

Comment: So, if I am adept at tinkering all sorts of office appliances (as any small office IT-manager), what tags should I browse to see where I can provide assistance? All of the mentioned tags? What I say is that there must be tag that encompasses all specific tags, like [printer] or [mouse].

Comment: @BarafuAlbino I don't think that's how tags work. If you browse `device`, you will only get questions that are explicitly tagged `device`, not `printer` or `mouse`.

Comment: [devices] can also refer to mobile devices, such as the iPhone, so [peripherals] wouldn't cover it.