# Meat tag needs killing: [Devices]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tag-cleanup-request

[devices](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/devices) does not seem to help a question. Although [already proposed](https://meta.superuser.com/questions/6594/burnination-of-device-tag) last year, it still is running rampant with over 290 questions!

Comment: For those who don't get the pun: Meat is an anagram of *Meta*

Comment: Puns: you're doing it grown.

Comment: I still don't get what the pun is...

Comment: @mehdrad meat is what's left when an animal has been killed, like I want this tag to be

Comment: @CanadianLuke dead or alive, it's still team.

Comment: @JacobRaccuia Yea, a *team* **mate** that doesn't need to be here :P

Comment: The devices tag is no more.